# Chaining "Count of Columns" of a Method to Single Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have set models properly and I can use this and return as json.

```
$profile = Profile::with('user')->find($id);
```

I can also add `->with('likes')` to the chain and get all the like objects. However, what I want to do is get the count of the like rows (i.e total no. of likes = total no. of rows). I know I can use a separate query with `->count()`, and add it manually to the $profile variable, but what is the way of making the call in one query?

What is the way of achieve this properly?

My dummy trial:

```
$profile = Profile::with('user')->with(likes.count)->find($id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify anything, since Laravel returns a collection of "likes" you can use the `count()` method, like so :

```
$profile = Profile::with(['user','likes'])->find($id);
$profile->likes->count();
```

More information about collections can be found in the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$profile = Profile::with('user')->count('likes')->find($id);
```